# SQL - Can I pass a variable to be used in the FROM statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can I pass a variable to a `SELECT` statement?

I keep getting an error message saying I need to declare it.

However, it is declared.

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM @database_table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use dynamic sql statements to build your select statement.

```
-- Procedure input parameters
@TableName varchar(50)

-- Query guts
Declare @sql varchar(2000)
Set @sql = 'Select columnname from ' + @TableName
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks, hit the up arrow for me :)

Comment: can there be muluiple green checks?

Answer (score 7):

You are looking to use Dynamic SQL to perform this type of query.

[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Here is a quick sample

```
declare @sqlstatement nvarchar(4000)
declare @table sysname
set @table = 'yourTableName'

set @sqlstatement = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table)
exec(@sqlstatement)
```

Answer (score 0):

The one time you can do what you want is when you use table variables.  You have to define the variables as:

```
declare @name table (<column list>)
```

This is alternative method of declaring a temporary table.

Other than this, I fully agree with bluefeet.  You should read the link he posted.